# I cant move my object while moving the Artboard

Tags: adobe-illustrator, artboard

[image]

I can't move my object while moving the Artboard.

I tried to check "Move Artwork with Artboard" but it doesn't work....

I could do this before , then don't know why it doesn't work for now.

Comment: is the object outside the artboard? Also, is this Illustrator? Please mention the name of the software when you ask a question.

Comment: Is the artwork locked or the layer the artwork is on locked"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For illustrator, make sure the Move/Copy Artwork with Artboard option is checked when using the artboard tool. The Artwork may need to be completely encompassed by the artboard, and not on a locked or hidden layer.

[image]

Illustrator 2017

Answer (score 0):

It could be the file. In my case I had the typical spinning wheel on my mac, so i couldn't move the artboard in illustrator. That was solved when I created a new file.